# How to get Order Id in View.php

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get the Order ID in the `View.php` file. Basically I created a button in `view.php` in the back-end. now I want to pass the order id through query string to the external URL.

- How can I get the Order id in above scenario?
- How can I open an external URL in new browser window.

Here is my code:

```
$this->_addButton('order_reorder', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print'),
    //  'onclick'   => "setLocation('".$this->getUrl('http://www.google.com')."')"
    'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . 'http://www.exportleftovers.co/leopardmagento/test.php?order_id=$order' . '\')',
    'class'     => 'go'                                 
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// assuming you are getting $order object in your file  
$url = "http://www.exportleftovers.co/leopardmagento/test.php?order_id={$order->getId()}"; 
$this->_addButton('order_reorder', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print'),
    'onclick' => "window.open('".$url."')")
);
```

Comment: thanks  Minesh Patel.... now i can open it in new window. Do you have an idea how can i get the "ORDER ID" in new window?

Comment: if you mean in test.php file use $orderId = $_REQUEST['order_id'];

Comment: thanks you so much Minesh Patel. its working now. thanks alot.

Comment: Hi now my "leopard label"button is showing when new order is received, but one thing is when canceled the order and again i re-order then "leopard label" button is not showing in the back-end any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hi now my "leopard label"button is showing when new order is received, but one thing is when canceled the order and again i re-order then "leopard label" button is not showing in the back-end any idea? 
below is the code of "view.php" file.

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_objectId    = 'order_id';
    $this->_controller  = 'sales_order';
    $this->_mode        = 'view';

    parent::__construct();

    $this->_removeButton('delete');
    $this->_removeButton('reset');
    $this->_removeButton('save');
    $this->setId('sales_order_view');
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    $coreHelper = Mage::helper('core');

    // Get the Order Id and also Make the new button for printing.


    $url = "http://www.exportleftovers.co/leopardmagento/api_call_get_orders_magento.php?order_id={$order->getId()}"; 
    $this->_addButton('order_reorder', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Leopard Label'),
                    'onclick' => "window.open('".$url."')"

    ));   

    if ($this->_isAllowedAction('edit') && $order->canEdit()) {
        $confirmationMessage = $coreHelper->jsQuoteEscape(
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure? This order will be canceled and a new one will be created instead')
        );
        $onclickJs = 'deleteConfirm(\'' . $confirmationMessage . '\', \'' . $this->getEditUrl() . '\');';
        $this->_addButton('order_edit', array(
            'label'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Edit'),
            'onclick'  => $onclickJs,
        ));
        // see if order has non-editable products as items
        $nonEditableTypes = array_keys($this->getOrder()->getResource()->aggregateProductsByTypes(
            $order->getId(),
            array_keys(Mage::getConfig()
                ->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')
                ->asArray()
            ),
            false
        ));
```